# Alt-Gr and keyboard level 3

Tags: keyboard, console, xmodmap

**PROBLEM:**

Alt-Gr is **not functional under X11**. It seems that keyboard level 3 (for 'at', 'euro', 'curly brackets', etc.) is not set up upon pressing Alt-Gr. In the **text console** (reached by Right-Shift Right-Alt 1), this problem does not occur.

Applying settings like:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym q = q Q at"
```

does not cure the problem.

**This problem is critical! The system is virtually unusable in X-Windows.**

What can be done?

**SETUP:**

uname -v: `Ub#45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 15 11:35:04 UTC 2021`

The file `/etc/default/keyboard` contains:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Using `xkeycaps/xev` shows that:

- Alt-Gr sends key code '108'

The `xmodmap` delivers

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Ouput of `xev` upon Alt-Gr.

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x251, subw 0x0, time 6145247, (1781,-38), root:(1804,42),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xff20, Multi_key), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x251, subw 0x0, time 6145491, (1781,-38), root:(1804,42),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xff20, Multi_key), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? This is usually fixed by tweaking the settings of the keyboard in the GUI. What keyboard layout have you set there? Did you use a German variant with dead keys?

Comment: No, not what it says in `/etc/default/keyboard`, presumably that's fine since you say it works outside the graphical environment. Since this is a GUI issue, the solution will most likely be in the GUI. So, what have you set _in the settings of your desktop environment_? And what desktop environment are you using? In any case, you probably just need to enable a version with dead key support. Or change the "key to choose third level" option in your GUI settings.

Comment: If it's Debian Linux (and derivatives like Ubuntu, (and if the DE / GUI doesn't alter the settings) `/etc/default/keyboard` applies to X also. Can you add another layout, `XKBLAYOUT="de,us"` `XKBVARIANT=",altgr-intl"` ? With this setup you could try `AltGr` on `us` layout, to test it.

Comment: at:Krackout: Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: at:terdon: running keyboard-configuration: PC105, German, German (dead acute), AltGr-default for keyboard layout, no compose key. No change.

Comment: Is there a safe way to 'Reset' the complete keyboard configuration?

Comment: Please add what `xev` outputs when you press AltGr. For Xmodmap, the keysym of @ is not `at`, but literally `@`.

Comment: It does not accept the at sign.

Comment: My feelding is, that the keyboard level 3 ist not activated or the usual Alt-Gr combinations are deactivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that switching keyboard profiles, somehow got the `xmodmap` settings confused. Further, the `Multi_Key` does not seem to replace the keyboard level 3 properly. So, I created a file `$HOME/.Xmodmap` by applying

```
> xmodmap -pke > .Xmodmap
```

The I changed the line in `.Xmodmap` which handles the key code 108, i.e. the one which `xev` identified as the Alt-Gr key:

```
keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift
```

Then reloaded it via

```
> xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

I waited for a few minutes. And voilá! I got my @ signs, my curly brackets, and my € sign back on my keyboard.

Comment: Mine says `keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift`. Would that be a problem?